# How do I redirect into a new browser window after server side validation suceeds with javascript?

Tags: spring, validation, spring-mvc

I have a form that needs to put its results into another window. I am using:

It has both client and server side validation.  The problem is when the server side validation fails, it puts the resulting error screen in the new window rather on the original page (as it should).

What I'm trying to figure out is how to have the server side validation occur and create the window only if there is no errors.  I would prefer not to rely on javascript.

Using Spring 3 MVC.

Comment: That's not possible without JavaScript. Opening new windows is a purely client-side task and can't (directly) be triggered server-side.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Javascript for the client-side validation?
I don't think there are any other options for opening a new window besides javascript's 'window.open()' and the target="_blank"-attribute of a Anchor-tag or Form-tag.

Comment: I have come to the conclusion that I will have to validate, set an error code, return to the original page and then if there is no error, pop open a window.